# Fontawesome-fx jar has no UI components in Scene Builder

Tags: java, android, javafx, material-design, javafx-8

I've been trying to use Fontawesomefx in my JavaFX application to enrich my UI design but after downloading the Jar file and uploading it into scene builder, it shows no UI components. When I search in SceneBuilder, I get to use it alright but then I can't use it in my Java code. PS. I've tried multiple versions of Jens fontawesome jars and I'm using Java 10. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change the SceneBuilder with gluon. https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download 
after that import jar fontawasomefx.

i hope that helps. sorry my english little bad.